# illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions even though session is closed

Tags: hibernate, session

I am getting an issue of open sessions even though the session is been closed.

//This is Action class code where I am making a call to Service class

```
TPrfleService tPrfleService=new TPrfleService();
tPrfleService.save(prfle);
```

//This is my `save()` in service class

```
public void save(TPrfle prfle) {
    TPrfleExtndDAO tPrfleExtndDAO;
    try{
        tPrfleExtndDAO = new TPrfleExtndDAO();
        tPrfleExtndDAO.save(prfle);
    }catch(Exception e){
        LoggerImpl.error(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }finally {
        tPrfleExtndDAO = null;
    }
}
```

//This is my `save()` in DAO class

```
public void save(TPrfle transientInstance) {
    LoggerImpl.info("saving TPrfle instance");
    try {
        getSession(true).saveOrUpdate(transientInstance);
        LoggerImpl.info("save successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        LoggerImpl.error("save failed"+ re);
        throw re;
    }finally{
        closeSession(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace. Show your `getSession` and `closeSession` methods.